# Invalid argument was supplied socket exception when running app from shared drive

Tags: .net, sockets, exception, path, shared

Live was good for a while until recent (May, 2018)  Windows 10 Update.
My .NET app that was working for years (5+) from shared drive started throwing an exception "Invalid argument was supplied" when trying to do any network operation (download file over http or connect to web service).

I googled the problem but all solutions are from 2012 and they do not apply anymore. Any one knows how to fix it?

PS: I confirmed that the problem is Shared drive (no problem when i move app to local folder). It has something to do with .NET security

Comment: Can you post a snippet of code that you are having problems with as well as the full exception? Without the snippet of code and full exception, the community won't be able to help you solve your issue.

Comment: Sorry, Matt. The snippet is pretty much any TCP/IP communication. The plain one would be (sorry, could not get code formatting to work)
    static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                using (WebClient cl = new WebClient())                    cl.DownloadFile("https://www.google.com", "c:\\tmp\\aa.htm");
                MessageBox.Show("Success");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something similar, I suppose. After installing the last Windows update (May 2018) the authentication method used in a WPF app I wrote does not work anymore.

I found two ways of making it work again:

1. Roll-back to previous Windows version
2. Copy the .exe application file to a local directory (for example Desktop)

It's not a solution, but a workaround that worked for my needings.

The exception thrown is:

> System.Net.SocketException (0x80004005): An invalid argument was supplied
>   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port) [...]

And the `Authenticate()` method in the application is the following (the exception is thrown at the `new TcpClient` constructor line):

```
    public static int Authenticate(string IPAddress, int port, string appInfo, ref string answerStr)
    {
        var encryptor = new Crypto();

        var xClient = new TcpClient(IPAddress, port);
        var xStream = xClient.GetStream();

        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName);
        IPAddress[] addr = null;
        var localIP = "";
        addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        foreach (IPAddress xAddr in addr)
        {
            if ((xAddr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
            {
                localIP = xAddr.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Send auth request
        string authStr = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString()}|{Environment.UserName}|{Environment.UserDomainName}|{Environment.MachineName}|{localIP}|{appInfo}";
        byte[] authSocket = encryptor.Crypt(authStr);
        Array.Resize(ref authSocket, xClient.SendBufferSize);
        xStream.Write(authSocket, 0, authSocket.Length);

        // Read auth answer
        byte[] answerSocket = new byte[xClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
        xStream.Read(answerSocket, 0, answerSocket.Length);
        answerStr = encryptor.DeCrypt(answerSocket);

        if (!answerStr.ToUpper().StartsWith("Permission denied"))
        {
            var role = -1;
            var roleStr = answerStr.Split('|')[0];
            Int32.TryParse(roleStr, out role);

            answerStr = answerStr.StripBegin(roleStr + "|");

            return role;
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
```

I hope it helps targeting the problem.

Comment: We opened a ticked on github. You might want to watch it for solution https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/755#issuecomment-391379561